# Do multikills give money

Tags: dota-2

As far as I know several kills in a row (killing spree, dominating etc) gives only higher bounties for the hero who did it but I was wonder do several quick kills (double/triple kill, ultra kill or even RAMPAGE) gives additional money to the person who did them?

Comment: On the contrary- killing sprees and etc. actually make YOU worth more when killed.

Comment: That is what I wrote: higher bounty for the hero who did it (who did killing spree etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nope there is no such bonus for now. It was often proposed by community but never implemented nor really commentend.

see here for example :

[bonus for kill streaks](http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=400935)